# Hide required parameters of routes in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

How could i hide the parameters of a get route in laravel 5?

I mean, a route can have required parameters, and also optional parameters, i would like to know how to hide that parameters.

Here's Laravel docs for [Route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters)

> You can capture segments of the request URI within your route:
>
> ```
> Route::get('user/{id}', function($id)
> {
>     return 'User '.$id;
> });
> ```

If my domain is: example.com, when i access to **example.com/user/201348** i would like that in the browser the URL be: **example.com/user** for example.

Comment: That just won't work. How do you think this would work anyways? If that was possible it would be a huge security risk. Imagine you are visiting some malicious site, but your browser is displaying `stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Then what do you recommend? i have a requirement of hide GET parameters from the url... should i instead hash the parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, please add a real example from your application to the question.

Comment: Actually that's the real scenario, that's the requirement

Comment: The question is *what is the requirement intended to solve?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is not a get route but a post route.

```
Route::get('user/', function(Request $request)
{
    return 'User '.$request->get('id');
});
```

But keep in mind:
You need to create a form to generate a post request.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user')) }}
    {{ Form::hidden('id', $userId); }}
    {{ Form::submit('Show user with id '.$userId); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```