# Laravel : How to hide url parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Here the scenario is I want to pass a variable which will be send from one page to another and in next page it's gonna store through a form. So I have passed the variable from first page to second page through the URL. But I want to hide the parameter in the URL. How do I do it?

Here is my route :

```
Route::get('/registration/{course_id}',[
   'uses'=>'AppController@getregistration',
    'as'=>'registration'
]);
```

And Controller :

```
public function getregistration($course_id)
{        
    return view('index')->with('course_id',$course_id);      
}
```

And first page this is how I send the value to first page:

```
<li> <a  href="{{route('registration',['course_id' => '1'])}}">A</a> </li>
```

Comment: Use **POST** instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076500/hide-required-parameters-of-routes-in-laravel-5-0   or   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-hide-url-parameter?page=1

Comment: Then How I send the value to ? I have edited the Qus..Can you check again please?
@RaxWeber

Comment: Instead of using `<a>` you've to build a form and using that you've to make a post request.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Post Method

Route

```
Route::post('/registration',['uses'=>'AppController@getregistration','as'=>'registration']);
```

View

```
{!!Form::open(array('url' => '/registration')) !!}
  {!! Form::hidden('course_id', '1') !!}
  {!! Form::submit('registration') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Controller

```
public function getregistration(Request $request)
{   
    $course_id = $request->input('course_id');
    return view('index')->with('course_id',$course_id);      
}
```

### Get method

use encryption method, it will show encrypted id in url

View

```
<li> <a  href="{{route('registration',['course_id' => Crypt::encrypt('1') ])}}">A</a> </li>
```

Controller

```
public function getregistration($course_id)
{    
  $course_id = Crypt::decrypt($course_id);    
  return view('index')->with('course_id',$course_id);      
}
```

Comment: nice one @imran

Answer (score 1):

here is no way you hide parameter in url, rather then you convert parameter value encrypt or hash is up to you,

other-way is save value in session first, then call the value from session without define parameter in url.

because laravel route only working to pattern of url /string /id, post get. dynamic value you must be writing / getting using pattern method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide a parameter in `URL`. If you don't want to show the `ID` then try using `SLUG`. I hope you understand what is a `SLUG`. If you don't then here it is. If you course title is **My new Course Title** then its slug would be **my-new-course-title**. And make sure it is **unique** like an `ID` in the table. It is also good for SEO, readable and looks good.